# How can I change this path?

Tags: software-installation, configure

I built the glibc-2.11 with arm-none-linux-gnueabi version 4.4.1.
And I copy binaries to my board's rootfs.
When I type "ldconfig", I met following errors.

```
**ldconfig: Can't open configuration file /home/gykim/working/s1cam/gykim/stream/bsp/linux/util/glibc-2.11/_install/etc/ld.so.conf: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Can't create temporary cache file /home/gykim/working/s1cam/gykim/stream/bsp/linux/util/glibc-2.11/_install/etc/ld.so.cache~: No such file or directory**
```

My configure options as follows.

```
*../configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --enable-add-ons=../glibc-ports-2.11,nptl,libidn CFLAGS='-O3' --prefix=/home/gykim/working/s1cam/gykim/stream/bsp/linux/util/glibc-2.11/_install*
```

Actually, I want to change these path to `/etc/` without don't modify prefix.
How can I change this path?

Answer (score 0):

I found it by myself.
Add following in the config.make.in file.

```
install_root = *$(DESTDIR)*
```

And type `DESTDIR=*install_dir*` in the command line.

```
$ ../configure ~~~
$ make
$ make install DESTDIR=${DESTDIR}
```

Then, the install directory is DESTDIR, and system dir is prefix.